# separate chaining in C

Tags: c

I am writing a code that uses separate chaining in C in order to store two or more values on the same index on my hash table if a collision occurred. but now I did not get how to put multiple values on the same hash table index.
My code below deletes the oldest value on the same index and gets only the new one.
what am I missing here?

```
void ht_set( hashtable_t *hashtable, char *key, char *value ) {
int bin = 0;
entry_t *newpair = NULL;//
entry_t *next = NULL;
entry_t *last = NULL;

bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key );//function to calculate hash index value

next = hashtable->table[ bin ];

while( next != NULL && next->key != NULL && strcmp( key, next->key ) > 0 ) {
last = next;
next = next->next;
}

/* There's already a pair. Let's replace that string. */
if( next != NULL && next->key != NULL && strcmp( key, next->key ) == 0 ) {

free( next->value );
next->value = strdup( value );

/* Nope, could't find it. Time to grow a pair. */
} else {
newpair = ht_newpair( key, value );

/* We're at the start of the linked list in this bin. */
if( next == hashtable->table[ bin ] ) {
newpair->next = next;
hashtable->table[ bin ] = newpair;
/* We're at the end of the linked list in this bin. */
} else if ( next == NULL ) {
last->next = newpair;
/* We're in the middle of the list. */
} else {
newpair->next = next;
last->next = newpair;
}
}
}
```

And here is my structs

```
struct entry_s {
char *key;
char *value;
struct entry_s *next;
};

typedef struct entry_s entry_t;

struct hashtable_s {
int size;
struct entry_s **table;
};

typedef struct hashtable_s hashtable_t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, don't understand you code quite right, here is my version:

```
struct node {
  char* key,*value;
  node* next;
} *hashtable[table_size];

void AddNode(char* key,char* value)
  {
    struct node* newnode=malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    node->key=key;node->value=value;
    node->next=hashtable[hash(key)];
    hashtable[hash(key)]=node;
  }

struct node* FindNode(char* key)
  {
    struct node* node=hashtable[hash(key)];
    while(node!=NULL&&strcmp(key,node->key)!=0) node=node->next;
    return node;
  }
```

If you need to delete from table as well, change the code to use double linked list.

Comment: but what if collision happened? I mean if two values or more on the same hash index? your code will delete the oldest value on the hash table index and restore the newest one. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it will not. It will simply add the new member to the linked list 'bunch'.

Comment: I have written this it keeps delete the old value and returns only new one

Comment: You should USE THE FUCTION FindNode to get value instead of picking up the value from array!!!

Comment: I have misunderstanding  here what I really want from FindNode function to do is to ask user to enter the value to be searched and it is works fine but my problem is with the function AddNode because if I made two calls on my main function to this function each time with different value it keeps replace the old one with the new one!! and I do not want this to happen I just want both values .

Comment: Can you show me how are you checking that the old value is replaced?

Comment: I just wrote this on my main function :                       ht_set( hashtable, "key1", "1" );
ht_set( hashtable, "key1", "2" );  and then call my get function printf( "%s\n", ht_get( hashtable, "key1" ) ); it just keeps printing 2

Comment: You don't understand what chaining is! A collision is when two DIFFERENT keys will have the same hash. What you are getting is not collision, but an overwrite, and of course it cannot be resolved by ANY method. By the way, our implementations don't handles overwrites - DON'T use them! Nothing, no algorithm in the world can help you with such overwrite. What chaining is for is: ht_set(table,"key1","1");ht_set(table,"koy1","foo");//where hash(key1)=hash(koy1). THIS is called collision and will be resolved: ht_get("key1")=="1";ht_get("koy1")=="foo";!!! What you are doing will never work.

Comment: oppps thanks a lot dear that was really helpful to me it was very helpful great thanks :)